# How to install import_3dm add-on properly?

Tags: add-on, installation, external-applications

I'm totally new to blender - mostly work in Rhino, but am wanting to use it to render models that I build in rhino so am trying to install the ["import 3dm" addon](https://github.com/jesterKing/import_3dm).

I had blender 2.80 installed. Tried installing the addon from the .zip file on my desktop (`import_3dm-master`) it shows a message in blue in the bottom right of the screen stating that it has installed that addon but it doesn't show in the addon menu under any of the categories.

I tried extracting the file and copying it directly into the addon folder. Still nothing. Tried installing the `import_3dm-v0.0.2` version. This shows up in the menu but has an error (shown in screenshot below). I even installed blender 2.82a in the hopes that this would somehow solve the problem but no luck... Here is the error message I get:

[image]

**Q:** How to install this add-on properly?

Comment: Hi. Can you provide a link to the add-on? Would save some time searching for the right one...

Comment: Thanks, i edited it into the original post

Comment: You haven't installed the rhino3dm package. You really *should not* follow the instructions provided on the GitHub page though, because that's not how packages should be installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 3dm importer depends on the [rhino3dm](https://github.com/mcneel/rhino3dm) package that has to be installed as well. In order to get the add-on working:

1. Install `rhino3dm`.
2. Install the 3dm importer add-on.

The first step can be accomplished by running the following script. Open Blender, switch to the *Scripting* workspace, copy and paste the script into the text editor and execute it. Make sure to check the output on the console for any error messages (*Window > Toggle System Console*). If everything works properly it should print the version of the installed package.

In case your Blender installation is located in `C:\Program Files\` you will have to start Blender as administrator. Otherwise, it doesn't have the permission to install the package.

```
import bpy
import os
import ensurepip
import subprocess


try:
    import rhino3dm
except ImportError:
    # The import failed, therefore we check ensure that pip is available and attempt to install the package.
        
    # ensurepip.bootstrap() also calls pip, which adds the environment variable PIP_REQ_TRACKER. After 
    # ensurepip.bootstrap() finishes execution, the directory doesn't exist anymore. However, when subprocess 
    # is used to call pip, in order to install a package, the environment variables still contain 
    # PIP_REQ_TRACKER with the now nonexistent path. This is a problem since pip checks if PIP_REQ_TRACKER is 
    # set and if it is, attempts to use it as temp directory. This would result in an error because the 
    # directory couldn't be found. Therefore, PIP_REQ_TRACKER needs to be removed from os.environ.
    ensurepip.bootstrap()
    os.environ.pop("PIP_REQ_TRACKER", None)
        
    # Try to install the package. This may fail with subprocess.CalledProcessError
    subprocess.run([bpy.app.binary_path_python, "-m", "pip", "install", "rhino3dm"], check=True)
    
    import rhino3dm
    
    
print(rhino3dm.__version__)
```

Next download and install the [most recent release of add-on](https://github.com/jesterKing/import_3dm/releases). With the required dependency installed it should activate without any issues.

**Important:** In case you intend to use the code above in an add-on, it's common courtesy to not connect to the internet or install packages without the explicit consent of the user.

Comment: Thank you - that was ultimately helpful but somewhat confusing.
I think either because i have version 2.82 installed or because i have Anaconda installed, it kept coming up with an error related to the pip - i eventually figured out to remove the lines of code relating to it ("import ensurepip" and " ensurepip.bootstrap()) and it seemed to work albeit only after figuring out that i then needed to run Blender as an administrator... Only read your edit after figuring that part out as well...

Anyways, thank you very much for the help!

Comment: @ToniHughes You're welcome. If this answer solved your problem, consider marking it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark next to it.

Comment: Tested on osx and it's working fine too (when running Blender as super user however).